# Como transformar uma coluna com uma frase por linha em uma coluna onde cada linha é uma palavra destas frases?

Tags: r, join, merge, columns

Possuo a seguinte estrutura:

```r
structure(list(frases = c("agricultura pecuária e serviços relacionados", 
"produção de lavouras temporárias", "cultivo de cereais", 
"cultivo de arroz", "cultivo de milho", "cultivo de trigo", "cultivo de outros cereais não especificados anteriormente", 
"cultivo de algodão herbáceo e de outras fibras de lavoura temporária", 
"cultivo de algodão herbáceo", "cultivo de juta", "cultivo de outras fibras de lavoura temporária não especificadas anteriormente", 
"cultivo de canadeaçúcar", "cultivo de canadeaçúcar", "cultivo de fumo", 
"cultivo de fumo")), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Preciso juntar todas as palavras de cada frase (linha) em apenas uma coluna, ficando mais ou menos assim:

```r
structure(list(palavras = c("agricultura", "pecuária", "e", "serviços", "relacionados", 
"produção", "de", "lavouras", "temporárias", "cultivo", "de", "cereais", 
"cultivo", "de", "arroz", "cultivo", "de", "milho", "cultivo","de", "trigo", "cultivo","de", "outros", "cereais", "não", "especificados", "anteriormente")), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")
```

O que fiz até o momento:

```
frases <- str_split(palavras_cnae_agro$palavras, fixed(" "))

palavras <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(frases), nrow=590, byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

MAS Isso me resultou em um data.frame com 590 linhas (quantidade de frases) e 7 colunas. Sendo cada célula uma palavra.

Não estou conseguindo juntar estas 7 colunas em apenas uma com todas as palavras.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se entendi o que você quer como resultado:

```
data.frame(palavras = unlist(strsplit(palavras_cnae_agro$palavras, ' ')))
```

**EDITADO**

Ao invés de usar `' '` como espaço, é recomendado usar a sintax `\\s+` do regex que considera todos os tipos de espaço:

```
data.frame(palavras = unlist(strsplit(palavras_cnae_agro$palavras, '\\s+')))
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39279181/6532002

Comment: Perfeito! Muito obrigado!

Comment: Percebi que algumas palavras vieram juntas, como "exceto móveis" e quando transformei em um vetor, ficaram na forma "exceto\nmóveis". Sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesta resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39279181/6532002
Ela considera todos os formatos de "espaço".

Answer (score 3):

Apesar de já haver uma resposta aceite, eis uma solução com `scan`.

```
data.frame(palavras = scan(what = character(), 
                           text = palavras_cnae_agro[[1]]))
```

Comment: Muito bom também! Obrigado!